# GoogleのGCMでPush通知電文が届かない事がありますか？

Tags: android, gcm

GCMを使ってPUSH通知を行うプログラムを作っています。
Android端末にPush通知されるのですが、通知内容が届かないケースがあります。
GCMからはエラーがでていません。

Pushで通知した電文がロストする事があるのでしょうか。
ご存じの方が居ましたら、教えて頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)になりMessage Pushの信頼性も改善されたようですが, GCMがクライアントに届かないケースはあります.
[こちら](https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/)でいくつか取り上げられているので参考になれば幸いです.

他にもAndroid6.0で追加された機能`Doze`ではhigh-priorityなPushでないとTTLに従って破棄されます.

> when using normal priority (the default priority), there are a number of different behaviors when the device is in Doze, including:
>
> - The most important change is that messages will be batched for devices in Doze. When the device enters its idle maintenance window, the batch of messages will be received.
> - We discard messages whose time_to_live expires while the device is in Doze (including TTL=0).

[How Google Cloud Messaging handles Doze in Android 6.0 Marshmallow](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2015/10/how-google-cloud-messaging-handles-doze.html)